# null is not an object (evaluating 'RCTAsyncStorage.multiMerge')

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I recently upgraded to Expo SDK 43.

I am now getting this error:

[image]

The line of code throwing it is:

```
if (!RCTAsyncStorage.multiMerge) {
```

I am on the latest version of AsyncStorage.

This seems to be due to my usage of firebase-js-sdk.

Unfortunately as this is an iOS/Android/Web project, it's necessary.

When I mock my Firebase exports, everything works:

```
const auth = () => {};

const analytics = () => {};

export default { auth, analytics };
```

But when I use the firebase-js-sdk functions, I get the above message.

This code causes an error (whichever version of auth I use)

```
let auth = initializeAuth(config, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
//let auth = getAuth(config);
let analytics = getAnalytics(config);

export default { auth, analytics };
```

Comment: can you add reproducible GitHub example ?

Comment: From which package do you import AsyncStorage?

Comment: @SyedAffanHamdani @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Comment: May be this helps you: https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/709

Comment: @SyedAffanHamdani It does not. I am "haveamission" in that thread, so I've read it and commented on it. The user's solution is to use secure storage - but that is an iOS and Android technology only. It does not work on web, and my solution MUST work on web as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid that specific error by adding optional chaining (the question mark '?'):

```
if (!RCTAsyncStorage?.multiMerge) {
```

It will shortcircuit to `undefined` (thus making the *if* `false`) instead of throwing error from trying to check in the null object.

As to why `RCTAsyncStorage` would be null, you would have to check where you first get/declare it, and traceback to the point it didn't load, maybe you are using something conflicting from firebase-js-sdk.

Also `multiMerge` might not be supported always as mentioned in the [docs](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#multimerge):

> multiMerge
> [...] **NOTE**: This is not supported by all native implementations.

Comment: All of this is happening in an included library (a fairly major one), so just editing the library is out of the question. I guess I'll have to continue tracing and figure out what's happening

Comment: You need a reproducible example to track better where the error is coming from, too many things could be happening as it is, which only indicates to the third party library.